# Designing "Friend" relationships across two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, relationship

I have User table and a join table to document "Friendship" between users. I have a question on how to document the "Friendship" relationship.

```
User Table
u_ID  | u_Name
-------------
1     |  bob
2     |  jill
```

Let's say bob and jill are friends. Should the join table document the friendship in both directions?

Bi-Directional relationship??

```
Friends Table
f_ID | u_ID1 | u_ID2
--------------------
1    |   1   |   2
2    |   2   |   1
```

Or a single directional relationship is enough??

```
Friends Table
f_ID | u_ID1 | u_ID2
--------------------
1    |   1   |   2
```

My use case is close to a friend relationship on Facebook. If I'm a friend of yours, then you are a friend of mine (We both need to endorse the relationship though). tx.

Comment: single directional relationship is enough. is it possible to be a friend of her and she is not a friend of you?

Answer (score 3):

Since the friend relationship is always two-way, you must not store two lines, but only one.

1. Option:

   You could decide that the first field in the table is the one that initiated the friendship. I would add two more rows : date and confirmed.
2. Option

   Store in the first field the lower user_id and in the second field the higher user_id. This allows you to define a `unique index (field1, field2)` and a `constraint field1 < field2`. This way you enforced the unicity of the friendship relationship.

   On the other hand you need an aditional field to store who initiated the friendship (use 0/1, not user_id)

Comment: @Declan_K He didn't say that it should be stored twice.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a score field as an int?

- Set to 1, id1 -> id2 is accepted,
- 2 is id2 -> id1.
- if you need more types of relationship afterwards, use higher numbers (its bit maths, so 4, 8, 16 etc).

This is slightly more code to operate, but is efficient in diskspace.  How many million rows do you need to process?

To list id1's friends

```
select u_id, u_name from users join Friends on u_id=id2 where id1= @X and (score % 2) =1;
```

To list id2's

```
select u_id, u_name from users join Friends on u_id=id1 where id2= @X and (score & 1)=1;
```

Both statements may be written with bitmaths.